# Emails going into junk and spf records

Tags: email, spf

our emails are being flagged as junk. I have two different webistes both with their own dedicted ip address.

sitea.com = xx.xx.xx.43
siteb.com = xx.xx.xx.44

Im using hmailserver to host our emails and have the smtp bound to the ip address of xx.xx.xx.42

im aware that i can set up a spf record to state that the what servers emails can be sent from

v=spf1 mx ip4:xx.xx.xx.43 mx:mail.sitea.com ip4:xx.xx.xx.42 -all

Would the fact that email are not sent from the sites ip's be causing them to be flagged as junk.

Cheers

Cam

Answer (score 2):

Having SPF that doesn't match the mail server is a sure fire way to get flagged as spam. Having an SPF that does match in general buys you nothing.

Have you checked if your server is on any realtime blacklists?

Answer (score 1):

> v=spf1 mx ip4:xx.xx.xx.43 mx:mail.sitea.com ip4:xx.xx.xx.42 -all

I don't think you want that record - generally using the `mx:` types doesn't get what you want.  You've also said that the `.42` address is the one you send from, so it should be first, and realistically the only record:

```
v=spf1 ip4:xx.xx.xx.42 -all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try www.mxtoolbox.com it has a simple blacklist checker which should be able to detect any blacklists that your on!
What are you settings in hmail for outgoing email?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

If your mail is being sent to junk folders, adjust your SPF and check again.